# Cannot retrieve number val of $firebaseObject

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have an issue where I can't retrieve a number value from a `$firebaseObject` in AngularFire.

if I `console.log($scope.slideGen)` the value correctly shows up in the log output of the entire object, but if I
`console.log($scope.slideGen.time)` then I get `undefined`.

Got the following code in a controller

```
Auth.$onAuth(function(authData) {
      $scope.userKey = authData.uid;
      $scope.ref = Ref.child('users').child($scope.userKey);
      loadSlide();
    });

function loadSlide() {
      if ($scope.slideKey !== '') {

        $scope.slide = $firebaseObject($scope.ref.child('slides').child($scope.slideKey));

        $scope.slideGen = $firebaseObject($scope.ref.child('slidesGeneral').child($scope.slideKey));
        $scope.time = new Date(1970, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0).setSeconds($scope.slideGen.time);
        console.log('Current time set to: ' + $scope.slideGen.time); //This returns undefined
      }
    }
```

Comment: You haven't waited for the data to be fetched from the server. The client can't know the value until it is requested.

Comment: @Kato if I do a console.log($scope.slideGen); just above my other log statement it correctly returns the object

Comment: `console.log` is a notoriously bad way to troubleshoot asynchronous data loading, since it will "update" data in the console after it's been loaded. If you **must** use it, do `console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.slideGen));` But if you use `if (authData) loadSlide();` in your `$onAuth` handler, you'll be off to a better start.

Comment: Ok, thanks Frank, I will give that a go